# How to select string with less amount of specfied xml tag with sql

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table where each item have a `nvarchar(max)` item with `xml` text.
I need some way to chose string with `xml` in which less amount of specified tag.
How to do this in faster way?
I read about `STRING_SPLIT` but it supported only with db with compatibility level 130 and I have compatibility level 110.

So for example I have two xml:

```
<main tag>
<child>
</child>
<child>
</child>
</main tag>
```

and

```
<main tag>
<child>
</child>
</main tag>
```

I need to take

```
   <main tag>
    <child>
    </child>
    </main tag>
```

Because the quantity of `<child>` tag in the second xml is less then in first xml string.

**SOLUTION**
I have found the solution. And Its pretty simple.

```
Declare @TempXML Table (XMLText XML)
Insert into @TempXML 
Select t.XMLString from dbo.MyXMLProcedure t
```

Then

```
Select t.XMLText.VALUE('count(/main tag/child)','int') from @TempXML t
```

Comment: What db level are you at? What does "less amount of specified tag" mean?

Comment: I have edited the text of question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Based on "compatibility level 130" it is MS SQL Server, but since the level desired isn't specified, that is still insufficient. (Presumably below 130.)

Comment: The compatibility level of my db is 110. And I'm interesting the solution for MS SQL sever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can't determine the number of XML tags in an XML string using simple string operations, but assuming you are willing to live with the limitations, you can use:

```
(len(@string) - len(replace(UPPER(@string), UPPER(@xmltag), '')))/len(@xmltag)
```

to count the number of occurrences of a specific tag (e.g. use @xmltag = `'<CHILD'`).

If you were working with an XML datatype column, you could use the XQuery `count` function:

```
SELECT xml.value('count /Main/Child')
FROM table
```

Comment: Yes It's works. But the only question how does it fast solution?

Comment: Ok what If I create table variable with XML column and insert into it all nvarchars with xml. What solution will be in that case ? Actually I can do this. And i works for table with XML type column

Comment: Relative to what? That depends on your environment (server speed, RAM, disk, etc.) and database / string size. I wouldn't recommend it as an ideal way to handle anything. If you can change the database to store the desired tag counts that would be much better on query, but then again, that depends on whether this query happens often.

Comment: The xml generating with stored procedure and doesn't store in the database. The problem is in the procedure that I can't to change. The xml is the format for message system and each <child> tag is a new warning for specific item. I need to take message with the less quantity of warnings.